# Hybris 2105 Gigya addon not present

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

I'm trying to install the gigyaloginaddon from customer data cloud extension but it's not present in hybris 2105, am I missing something? Do the name changed? It's no longer available for 2105 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the SAP Commerce 2005 release, the integration extensions are in a separate extension pack: SAP Commerce Cloud, Integration Extension Pack.  Installation docs here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/2f43049ad8e443249e1981575adddb5d/2108/en-US/8a7b6d2255e6437b804ac9327fa74936.html

Note: The Integration Extension Pack is released a little after the main SAP Commerce release.  So for SAP Commerce 2105, the corresponding version is SAP Commerce Cloud, Integration Extension Pack 2108

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure how they manage their versions, but here is the most recent CDC integration doc: https://help.sap.com/viewer/b6a1e8b75222421a8faf0269e8fbd0dc/2108/en-US/4fc06a3539a940e6b707c0c543d44053.html